# SQL query optimization - multiple rows from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, entity-attribute-value, sql-optimization

I have my tables like this (currently)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `user_opts` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `opt1` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt2` TINYINT(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `opt3` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`)
);
```

I want to be able to do queries like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM users
WHERE 
    id = 1 AND (
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM user_opts WHERE user_opts.user_id = users.id AND user_opts.opt1 = 'a' AND user_opts.opt3 = 'c') OR
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM user_opts WHERE user_opts.user_id = users.id AND user_opts.opt1 = 'b' AND user_opts.opt2 = 1)
    );
```

and this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM users
WHERE 
    id = 1 AND (
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM user_opts WHERE user_opts.user_id = users.id AND user_opts.opt1 = 'a' AND user_opts.opt3 = 'e') AND
        EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM user_opts WHERE user_opts.user_id = users.id AND user_opts.opt1 = 'b' AND user_opts.opt2 = 1)
    );
```

The obvious problem I'm starting to have is that the more users the queries goes slower and slower. I know I could refactor the first type of the queries (using `OR`) by JOINing the table, but the JOIN itself would be slow since I can't have a PK on the `user_opts` table.

How could I restructure my data (and the queries) so I can do efficient/fast searches? Preferably, if possible, I would like to keep the same queries for both `AND` and `OR` types, just switching the condition between the two.

[DB Fiddle url](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejE4aZZj5JhEToaGVBBcug/2)

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a 1:n relationship or 1:1?

Comment: 1:n, that's why I can't have a PK on the `user_opts` table (with the current structure at least)

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select user_id
from user_opts uo
where opt3 = 'c' or opt2 = 1
group by user_id
having sum(opt3 = 'c') >= 1 and
       sum(opt2 = 1) >= 1;
```

This handles the case when the two options are set on the same row in `user_opts`.

Comment: It doesn't seem that this makes it any faster, sadly. I've tried this way on the production database and the result is the same, +-3%

Comment: To clarify (can't edit now) your query itself is fast, but when I use it as a subquery to select the name from users and add the `users.id = user_opts.user_id` condition that makes it slow.

Comment: @Andrew . . . As your data gets larger, this will slow down, but possibly less so than your version.

Comment: `OR` is notoriously inefficient at scale.  And the query seems to be missing `user_id=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two indexes would speed up the `EXISTS`:

```
INDEX(user_id, opt1, opt3)
INDEX(user_id, opt1, opt2)
```

Your schema is a variant on EAV, which is notoriously inefficient and clumsy.  Is there a good reason not to have opt2 and opt3 in `users`?